How to fix bug to register user in my ASP.NET Core MVC project
I am building an ASP.NET Core MVC project with identity accounts and when I hit the register button (in register page).
I got this exception:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FirstName', table 'VolunteerCenterDB.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__189_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)

I am confused if problem is my Users's model or in Program.cs.
I thought I should make firstName and lastName nullable, but I don't think this make sense. Since I have any other options I do not know what else I could do?
User.cs:
public class User : IdentityUser<string>
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VolunteerSignups> VolunteerSignups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StatusHistory> StatusHistories { get; set; }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VolunteerCenterMVCProject.Data;
using VolunteerCenterMVCProject.Models;
using VolunteerCenterMVCProject.Services.Interfaces;
using VolunteerCenterMVCProject.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

// Identity configuration
/*builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
*/
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

// Add MVC and Razor Pages
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

// Register services
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUsersService, UsersService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Seed data on application startup
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
    }

    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

// Configure middleware pipeline
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Map routes
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

Not sure but I will share the my DbContext:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VolunteerCenterMVCProject.Models;

namespace VolunteerCenterMVCProject.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VolunteerSignups> Signups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StatusHistory> statusHistories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            #region Categories
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasKey(x => x.CategoryId);
            #endregion

            #region Locations
            modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
                .HasKey(c => c.LocationId);
            #endregion

            #region VolunteerSingups

            modelBuilder.Entity<VolunteerSignups>()
                .HasKey(c => c.SignupId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<VolunteerSignups>()
                .HasOne(x => x.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.VolunteerSignups)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.VolunteerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<VolunteerSignups>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Event)
                .WithMany(e => e.VolunteerSignups)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.EventId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            #endregion

            #region StatusHistory
            modelBuilder.Entity<StatusHistory>()
                .HasKey(c => c.StatusHistoryId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<StatusHistory>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Event)
                .WithMany(x => x.StatusHistories)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.EventId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<StatusHistory>()
                .HasOne(x => x.User)
                .WithMany(x => x.StatusHistories)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ChangedBy)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            #endregion

            #region Events
            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .HasKey(c => c.EventId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Category)
                .WithMany(x => x.Events)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Location)
                .WithMany(x => x.Events)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.LocationId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .HasOne(x => x.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.Events)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedBy)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            #endregion
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        }
    }
}


I feel like you should show the bit where you try to insert a user without a FirstName? Or, you know, just give it a first name…

Firstly, the error message told us that FirstName is not nullable but it looks like you are trying to insert a user item without FirstName in the item. So that if you want to solve the issue, you might go to your database and change the FirstName to be Nullable, or give value to FirstName property, then you can check whether the issue is resolved or not. By the way, I checked in my side using a project integrate asp.net core default identity, I can see there's no FirstName column in the user table, so that I trust you could modify that column. https://i.sstatic.net/jUuaytFd.png

Two options:

a) Set FirstName and LastName are nullable, and create another page to fill it after register successfully using default page of Identity UI

b) Override Register page in order to add FirstName and LastName input in order to to set columns values.


I prefer to choose b)
Btw, please ensure you applied migrations after you using custom User instead of default one.
